Enrich Kafka with CDC data coming with debezium in Spark Streaming
I have a kafka stream which I am reading in spark streaming. Some metadata is present in Mysql which can be changed. I have setup a debezium which is sending CDC events to another Kafka topic. I need to enrich this data with latest metadata ? How do I achieve this spark streaming.
Example : Input stream : key_id,cost,value
Metadata : key_id,key_name.
Output : key_id,key_name,cost,value
I read about broadcasting but that would not work since it is mutable. Is storing the entire metadata in state a good option OR storing this metadata in redis would be beneficial.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
